Properties of $\frac{\sum _{k=1}^n (-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor +1}k}{n}$
Investigating the sum:
$$\frac{\sum _{k=1}^n (-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor +1}k}{n}$$
It seems it becomes integer enough rarely.
Here is the list of integers for $n<20000$
$$1, 3, 4, 8, 16, 20, 48, 1012.$$
Is there any idea if this list is infinite? My feeling is yes, but no idea how can I deal with this kind of sums.
Just one hint, count of negative $k$ or in other words number of $k$-s for which  $(-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{k}\right\rfloor +1}$ is positive/negative are:
$$a(n) = n -\left\lfloor n/2 \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor n/3 \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor n/4 \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor n/5 \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor n/6 \right\rfloor +...$$
$$a(n) = \left\lfloor n/2 \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor n/3 \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor n/4 \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor n/5 \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor n/6 \right\rfloor - ...$$
Not sure how this will help, but this may help
If we consider
$$\frac{\sum _{k=1}^n (-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor +1}}{n}$$
The integer values for $n<20000$ are:
$$1, 2, 3, 4, 8$$
Obviously this relation can becom integer only for the $n$ with sum equals to $0$ as the sum is obviously less than $n$.
Strangely the
$$\frac{\sum _{k=1}^n (-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor +1}k}{n+1}$$
becomes integer more frequently. For $n<20000$ the following $n$-s make it integer:
$$11, 35, 83, 91, 159, 516, 740, 1316, 1395, 2255, 2587, 3544, 4190, 18203$$

If you replace $k$ with $k^m$ under sum, then according to numerical evidence the result is integer for $n=1, 8$ - always, for $n=3,16$ - for odd $m$, for $n=4$ - for $m=1$ and for even $m$. There is however no clear pattern for larger $n$.

@user Thank you. Yes. I also try the same direction. Also trying to find a generating function for this.

The function $f(x)=(-1)^{\lfloor \frac1x \rfloor}$ on $0<x\leq1$ and $f(0)=0$ is Riemann integrable (its set of discontinuities is countable and hence of measure $0$)
The sum $A_n:=\frac1n\sum^n_{k=1}(-1)^{\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \rfloor +1}$ is a Rieamnn sum approximation to
\begin{align}
-\int^1_0 f(x)\,dx&= \sum^\infty_{n=1}\int^{\tfrac{1}{n}}_{\frac1{n+1}}(-1)^{n+1}\,dx=\sum^\infty_{n=1}(-1)^{n+1}\Big(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\Big)\\
&=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\Big(\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k}\Big)-\sum^\infty_{k=1}\Big(\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{2k+1}\Big)=2\log 2-1
\end{align}
Thus, the number of terms of the sequence $A_n$ that are integer must be finite.
The function $g(x)=(-1)^{\lfloor \tfrac1x\rfloor +1}x$ is also Riemann integrable and the sum
$$B_n=\frac1n\sum^n_{k=1}(-1)^{\lfloor \tfrac{n}{k}\rfloor +1}k=n\frac1n\sum^n_{k=1}g(k/n)\sim n\int^1_0g(x)\,dx$$
Now
\begin{align}
\int^1_0g(x)\,dx &=\sum^\infty_0\int^{\tfrac1n}_{\frac1{n+1}}(-1)^{n+1}x\,dx=\frac12\sum^\infty_{n=1}(-1)^{n+1}\Big(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\Big)=\frac12\big(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1\Big)
\end{align}
This suggests that the subsequence $B_n$ that are integers is rather sparse.
